# iOS Designer (Xamarin.iOS) makes ViewController disappear when new Segue is created

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I think the title explains my problem.

Whenever I try to make the Segue as in the Screenshots my ViewController disappears and is not editable anymore.
I need to create that Segue because the user should be able to log off.

[image: Before Segue]

[image: After Segue]

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a bug in the Xamarin iOS designer. Which channel are you on (stable, beta, alpha)? If it's an option, I would consider trying a different channel (like moving from stable to beta just to see if it's fixed). I've been using beta since April and I haven't seen this issue with segues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is anything like what I experienced, this can be corrected by changing the orientation of the device to horizontal then back again to vertical.

Comment: Yeah that works. 

Seems to be a bug but the iOS Designer is imo one big mess. Thinking about changing development device to Mac since there I can edit the storyboard  with XCode.